# Shift Reduce Parser walks in dead end

Tags: parsing

I implemented a Shift Reduce Parser which looks at every word and their preceding word and which tries to apply a reduction rule. This works in general really well, but for some sentences the algorithm applies a reduction rule and walks in a dead end. This basically happens when the word should have been used in a different reduction rule with the suceeding word which the parser doesn't know yet. How to solve this problem without creating (words_in_sentence)! parsing trees?

Comment: Except for a very small subset of languages, you cannot make a shift/reduce decision just on the basis of two consecutive tokens. (If gat is what you are done ng.) You mght want to read any standard textbook o.n parsing theory.

Comment: I am using this parser for a language with this kind of production rules, so I would be glad if you could actually help.

Comment: @fragrant: your question has not nearly enough information for me to offer anything other than a generality (such as "maybe you are looking for an Earley parser.")